# python equivalent of R getOption and options

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, package

I am creating a python package where I want to have some options such as a data directory, a database host and port, etc. In R, I generally do this using `options` and `getOption`. Is there a way to do this in python?

I researched a little bit and looked at pandas, in which they have options such as `pd.options.display.width`, but I didn't find it that intuitive. (May be because I am new to writing python packages)

Thanks.

Comment: You could try creating a new `.py` file and put all your variables there. When you want to call one (in another file), you just `from file import variable`, where file and variable are your `.py` file and "option", respectively.

Comment: Yeah. I should have mentioned that this is what I am currently doing. I was just not sure whether there was a pythonic way to do it.